# How to open local path pdf file from angular 2+

Tags: angular

I have Anchor element which is inside angular 2+ component.

```
<a href="file://tmpcmamva07/JobTrackerFileServer_Test/TempPDFFiles/pdf.pdf">Link</a>
```

When I click on it, I get error at browser console: 
**'Not allowed to load local resource: file://tmpcmamva07/JobTrackerFileServer_Test/TempPDFFiles/pdf.pdf'**

But, same link I tried creating inside sample HTML5 template, it works fine without throwing error.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<a href="file://tmpcmamva07/JobTrackerFileServer_Test/TempPDFFiles/pdf.pdf">Link</a>
</body>
</html>
```

One thing to add, angular 2+ runs on its server, where are html file doesn't have server and it is opened inside the browser.

How to make link work in angular 2+?

Answer (score 1):

Most browsers don't let you open a local file from a HTTP-Website.
That has nothing to do with Angular.

You probably opened your sample HTML as a local resource (file://... in your Navbar) and from a local resource you can open other resources. So if your HTML-File would be hosted on a server, it wouldn't work either. This is due to security-reasons.

Imagine what could happen, if some website could directly access your local files.

If you only need this personally, you can run your browser in a mode, where it allows such things.

For example Chrome: https://chrisbitting.com/2014/03/04/allow-local-file-access-in-chrome-windows/

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I guess, as per my knowledge, need to use virtual directory concept in order to access local files from IIS.